# Evict Ehcache elements programmatically, using Spring

Tags: spring, ehcache

I'm new to Spring and Caching, and I would like your help.

I'm caching Link object by using Spring annotation

```
@CachePut(value=CACHE_NAME, key="{#root.targetClass, #link.getId()}")
public Link update(Link link) {...}
```

Now, I want to programmatically clear those links that have been cached, so I tried this.

```
Ehcache cache = cacheManager.getEhcache(CACHE_NAME);
for(Link link : links) {
   List key = Arrays.asList(new String[] {this.getClass().toString(), link.getId()});
   cache.remove(key.toString());
}
```

So, I've noticed that is not working.
Do you know what SpEL's list ouput is? What key value need I expect in cache?

Thanks in advance,
TD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creating the cache key is a internal operation of the framework. Seem better option to use the public API to evict.

For example

```
@CacheEvict(value=CACHE_NAME, key="{#root.targetClass, #link.getId()}")
public Link evict(Link link) {
   // nothing to do
}
```

However I suppose that the following code will work

```
List key = new ArrayList();
key.add(LinkService.class);
key.add(link.getId());
cache.evict(key);
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but my goal was to delete a numerous of records with one query instead of calling into a loop the delete method which will also evict one by one the objects from cache. I guess that my approach is a bad practice. Thanks for the response. TD

Comment: Sorry, didn't refresh the post. I will try the second one. Thank you.

Comment: Hello Jose, I would like to thank you again for your response. Indeed this approach is working. Mistakenly I never used this approach. I was wrongly trying to create a string type key.  It was stuck in my mind that key check will be done by using a toString object of that SpEL list, which I set inside @CachePut.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CacheHelper {

    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    /**
     * Evicts all caches
     */
    public void evictAllCaches() {
        Collection<String> cacheNames = cacheManager.getCacheNames();
        cacheNames.stream().map(cacheManager::getCache)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .forEach(Cache::clear);
        log.debug("Caches evicted [{}]", cacheNames);
    }
}
```

I've made this little snippet to clear all the caches.